# Media queries in CSS - Doesn't work on MacBook

Tags: html, css, anki

As shown In the image below, pictures on Anki (an app which uses CSS) appears distorted on MacBook but not iMac presumably because the width is set to 600px. The reason I’ve done this is because when I take screenshots and paste, without a width specified the images are too big and I can’t view them easily.
Any ideas please?

```css
.card {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}

.centered-block {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 85vw;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto -15px auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 85vw;
  height: auto;
}

/* iPhone 13 Pro Max: 2778x1284 pixels at 458ppi */
@media only screen 
  and (device-width: 428px) 
  and (device-height: 926px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    .centered-block {
      max-width: 90vw;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 90vw;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: -20px;
    }
 }

/* Macbook Pro - DOES NOT WORK*/
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1440px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
    img {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

[image]

**strong text**

Comment: are you sure that the resolution 1280-1440 "catches" the macbook , because that would be my first guess that maybe it does not. If your pc has resolution higher than 1440 then no media query will be used ?

Comment: doesn't Mac use native scaling so 2560 x 1600 becomes 1280? even when I change it to 1000 and 1500 it doesn't work though

Comment: to be honest I'm not much of a macbook user :D but quick search in web says that for macbook pro the resolution should be 2560x1600 so I would thought that the max-width should be 2560. Try and add it because maybe it will work. Also I don't think you need the max-width in this case at all, because there is no other device you will look it up, over laptop so you can remove it and it should work